# How to tune InnoDB performance in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb, omnet++

I want to use Artery-LTE with OMNET++.
In the installation steps, i don't understand how can i do this step

[image]

When i open my.cnf file, i get these lines.
[image]

Comment: In newer Linux versions, MySQL config file is divided into different parts. Check `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` file. In that, look for a line containing `[mysqld]`. Just look for these variables in the lines below that. If you find them, you can update their values. Else, you can simply enter a new line at the end, with the variable name and its value. Once done, save the file and restart the mysql server

Comment: Hi @MadhurBhaiya , i checked this file and it just contain only one line [mysql]. So i enter new lines but i can't save the file

Comment: You will need to access this file with root user permission. for eg: `sudo nano my.cnf`

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between my.cnf, *.cnf and .my.cnf file and which one can be used to tune InnoDB performance ?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Answer (score 0):

- Those two include files have most of the settings.
- You could either modify one of them, or add your own.  If you add your own, be sure it is readable by mysql/mariadb.
- Wherever you put it, be sure it is in the `[mysqld]` section of the config file.
- Caution:  those settings assume you have 4GB of RAM.  Do you?